# Using Logstash how to push ElasticSearch data in Oracle database

Tags: logstash

```
I want to push data from Elasticsearch to an Oracle database using Logstash.
The configuration file should contain an input section and an output section. 
In the input section, we need to pass elastic search configuration and output section JDBC configuration.
```

Tried multiple ways but didn't work out.

```
Please let me know is this possible in Logstash. If yes, could you please help me with this? 

**Note:** Using the Logstash JDBC input plugin, I have successfully push data from an Oracle database to Elasticsearch.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to send data from Elasticsearch (input) to Oracle (output) you need:

- [Elasticsearch input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html)
- [JDBC output](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc)

JDBC output does not exist officially, I haven't used it before myself so I cannot give more info than this

Comment: Thank you. Let me try